# How to retrieve data from website to sql server [using sql]

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with one case related to retrieving data directly from website to sql database. 
My data on website is a weather condition data for 2016(separated by comma). 
I wrote some SQL procedure to download this data, but I received all data in one column. 
Also when I call procedure once again I receive NULL value. 
Is it possible to load this data directly to Table? If not do you have any idea how I can download this data to SQL table?

Below my sql code

```
DECLARE
@xmlObject INT,
@vResponseText VARCHAR(MAX),
@vStatus INT,
@vStatusText VARCHAR(200)
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @xmlObject OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @xmlObject, 'open', NULL, 'GET',                                             'https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EPWA/2016/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=31&monthend=12&yearend=2016&req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=&format=1'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @xmlObject, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @xmlObject, 'responseText', @vResponseText OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @xmlObject, 'Status', @vStatus OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @xmlObject, 'StatusText', @vStatusText OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OADestroy @xmlObject
SELECT @vResponseText
```

If I change second EXEC line command returns value in one rows: SQL code below:

```
DECLARE
@xmlObject INT,
@vResponseText VARCHAR(MAX),
@vStatus INT,
@vStatusText VARCHAR(200)
EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @xmlObject OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @xmlObject, 'open', NULL, 'GET',  'https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EPWA/2016/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=31&monthend=12&yearend=2016&req_city=&req_state=&req_statename=&reqdb.zip=&reqdb.magic=&reqdb.wmo=&format=1'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @xmlObject, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @xmlObject, 'responseText', --@vResponseText OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @xmlObject, 'Status', @vStatus OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @xmlObject, 'StatusText', @vStatusText OUTPUT
EXEC sp_OADestroy @xmlObject
SELECT @vResponseText
```

Thanks in advance!
Cezary

Comment: Assuming it's about MS Sql server, did you try and create a new table and use the import wizard to import the data manually?

Comment: Yea its right - is MS_SQL server. I can creata excel file, run the excel import wizard and download data, but I want to make direclty import.

Comment: In Powershell, retrieving a URL's data is possible with `Invoke-WebRequest` or one of its aliases, eg wget. You can replace the `<br />` line endings with `- replace "<bre />"`. A csv file can be inserted into SQL Server directly if it matches the table's schema. Otherwise you can use `Import-CSV` to import a CSV file into a variable and powershell commands like `Select-object` to select and rename columns as needed.

Comment: Finally, you can use ADO.NET classes to insert data into the database. Check for example [Bulk Copy Data Into SQL Server with Powershell](http://sqlmag.com/powershell/bulk-copy-data-sql-server-powershell)